# Manage storage from Settings

Tags: android, android-intent

I know that you can create an activity from which the user can control data usage. This is to avoid the situation when the user blocks all background network for my app. I want to give them a similar option, but concerning storage. As you see below there is a MANAGE SPACE option. How can I add that to my app to let the user delete some files if they want more space from my app.

Intent filter for the network settings activity:

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.MANAGE_NETWORK_USAGE" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

[image: Settings screen]

Comment: how do you store the data? do you save files? do you save data to sqlite?

Comment: I have both of them. Why?